# My app keeps running in the processes after exit

Tags: c#

I know this question is well asked and even better replied but i tried everything I found online and my winform app is still in the processes list in the task manager consuming RAM.

I'm using Quartz.NET and this is how I'm shutting down my app:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        scheduler.Shutdown();
        scheduler2.Shutdown();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I'm using two schedulers. I tried killing the processes inside my app, I used `FormClosing` but it's still there.

Edit: Turns out the event of `Form1_FormClosed` wasn't called and i had to add it by the form properties.

Comment: This might sound silly but have you waited 10 seconds? This is a default interval the application will wait before closing when all of the schedulers have stopped.

Comment: I've waited more than 10 minutes, still running. One thing i noticed is that as soon as i press exit the arrow on the left side of the name at the task manager disappears.

Answer (score 7):

Most potential reason is: another thread (other than UI thread) is still running, and preventing the process from terminating. You can force the application to terminate the process at the `FormClosed` event using

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Because `Application.Exit();` "tries" to exit the application normally, but the one in `Environment` class forces it to terminate immediately.

Comment: Doesn't this also abruptly kill all threads? That would mean that if a thread function has some graceful exit-code, that it won't get called.

Comment: @AngeloGeels The developer in this case is responsible about that. He either wants to prevent user from exiting if his thread is still running, or force the application to exit simply. But keeping its process running is totally meaningless

Comment: I used it still nothing.

Comment: There is no exception, the only thing that caught my eye is this: `no configuration section <common/logging> found - suppressing logging output`

Comment: Can your application be terminated using Task Manager ? If yes, the absolutely `Environment.Exit` will terminate it, because it calls OS windows functions to terminate the process

Comment: Yes through Task Manager i can terminate the app.

Comment: @George Please put a break point on the code and see if it is ever reaches it.

Comment: @Desolator `Form1_FormClosing/ed` never gets called.... I'm terminating the app usng the X button on the top right.

Comment: @George Add this event from properties window of your Form

Answer (score 0):

There must be a thread that is still running. You can set all your threads as a background threads using [Thread.IsBackground Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx). You will be sure that all threads has ended when main thread ends

Calling in this case `Environment.Exit(0);` is a bad practice. I would try to investigate which thread has not ended and what's going on after close

Comment: I'm talking about threads you created. You should know when. Try to make them all background and see if there is still a problem. You can also put simple console log in main thread function. If you're using 3rd party libraries - make sure you close them correctly